# The shortcut keys for cut, copy, and paste don't work in some applications

Tags: 11.04, shortcut-keys, clipboard

I have problem with my shortcut keys for cut, copy, and paste. they does not work on Netbeans and some other applications. I have to click the right mouse button and select the operations from the context menu.

I thought this problem comes from Unity, so I switch to the classic GNOME session, but this didn't help.

Comment: Could you please tell us more about your setup and when your problems started?

Comment: Can you tell us those 'some other apps'? Installing Netbeans is pretty heavy when trying to reproduce your problem. :)

Comment: @htorque I notice the problem in two Apps so far , Netbeans , and Second Life game .

Comment: @N.N.  I could not remember when it's started :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found  The solution Accidentally. So I Decided to post it here to help people who have same problem

the problem occurs when you have two layouts Keyboard and the first layout is not English

so to solve the problem you have to move English up . that is it ^_^

and thanks to **Emmet Hikory** ,**N.N** , and **htorque** for trying to help me

Answer (score 1):

Each application is independently responsible for binding keystrokes to specific operations.  While there are conventions (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is sometimes copy), sometimes different choices are made (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is sometimes EOT (end of text)).

Applications that are made for a given desktop environment (e.g. gedit Text Editor for GNOME) are very likely to inherit keybindings for that environment, but applications that use different frameworks (e.g. Netbeans for GNOME) are less likely to do so, although some conventions may be followed (i.e. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is copy for both gedit and Netbeans).

Some applications or frameworks may support additional keysyms (like `XF86Copy` for copy in gedit Text Editor (usually a dedicated <kbd>Copy</kbd> on the keyboard), whereas others will not (Netbeans ignores `XF86Copy`).  If you have customised keymappings, or complex input devices with special signals (like <kbd>Copy</kbd>), you may need to configure support separately in separate applications.

If a specific application does not support some key, and does not offer a way to configure a keybinding for that key, please file a bug requesting support for the appropriate keybinding.

If a specific application does not support some key, and does offer a way to configure a keybinding for that key, consider opening a bug to modify the default configuration to support that key, if you believe this would be a common keybinding, to be expected by default.

If you have specialised input needs (you do not believe that others will want this keybinding), and the application does not offer a means to configure the keybindings, you might open a bug requesting support for configurable keybindings.